# Как напечатать каждый элемент списка в отдельной строке в питоне

Tags: python

Читаю список из файла и печатаю:

```
with open('1_lst.txt', 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()
    print('\n'.join(map(str, text)))  # "[1,2,3,4,5]"
```

Но хочется вывести так:

```
1
2    
3    
4
5
```

Comment: Json load вместо open

Comment: На самом деле у меня не цифры в списке, а баркоды, которые выводятся в одну строку через пробел. А хотел их видеть в виде столбцов:

Comment: @Алекс Приведите пример. Но вообще тогда просто `split` будет без параметров, если по пробелам бить.

Answer (score 3):

Если у вас там именно такой текст в файле:

```
text = '[1,2,3,4,5]'
```

То, например, так, отрезав квадратные скобки "вручную":

```
print('\n'.join(text[1:-1].split(',')))
```

Или, что более правильно, вот так распарсить текст в питоновский список:

```
from ast import literal_eval
print('\n'.join(map(str, literal_eval(text))))
```

Ну или самое правильное - через `json`, конечно, как eri написал:

```
import json
print('\n'.join(map(str, json.loads(text)))
```

или

```
print('\n'.join(map(str, json.load(f)))
```

Вывод:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Answer (score 0):

**способ 1:**

использовать параметр `sep` в `print()`

```
print(*[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], sep='\n')
```

способ 2:

в лоб через `for`

```
for elem in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:
    print(elem)
```

из той же серии

```
[print(elem) for elem in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте цикл for - самый простейший способ:

```py
three = 3
for i in [1, "2", three, True]:
    print(i)
```

Получим следующее:

```
1
2
3
True
```